# Is there a secret way to get some character skins in Soul Knight?

Tags: soul-knight

I'm quite new to playing *Soul Knight*, and I find it quite enjoyable and entertaining. I see that there are skins in the game, but I just can't afford to buy one. Is there a secret thing or a secret mission to get some character skins?

Comment: Now I don't really know enough about this game to give a definitive answer, but in-app purchases are how these games finance themselves so the answer to this type of question is pretty much categorically "no". There are games where it's possible to get pretty much anything in the game via grinding, but in those types the grind typically won't be a secret; It'll be a sales argument, so the game will let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, I discovered that there is a possibility that you can win a free skin through the Arcade Claw Machine. Just collect some blue coins, and you can play at the Arcade Crane.